# WebFlux: why do I need to use flatMap in CRUD

Tags: crud, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, spring5

I found examples on the Internet but this doesn't give me a full understanding. **Standard CRUD when using WebFlux.**

**Router:**

```
@Configuration
public class PersonRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(PersonHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(GET("/getAllPersons").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::findAll)
                .andRoute(GET("/getPerson/{id}").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)), handler::findById)
                .andRoute(POST("/createPerson").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::save)
                .andRoute(DELETE("/deletePerson/{id}").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::delete);
    }

}
```

**Handler:**

```
@Component
public class PersonHandler {

    private final PersonService personService;

    public PersonHandler(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> findById(ServerRequest request) {
        String id = request.pathVariable("id");
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(personService.getById(id), Person.class);
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> findAll(ServerRequest request) {
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(personService.getAll(), Person.class);
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> save(ServerRequest request) {
        final Mono<Person> person = request.bodyToMono(Person.class);
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(fromPublisher(person.flatMap(personService::save), Person.class));
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> delete(ServerRequest request) {
        String id = request.pathVariable("id");
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(personService.delete(id), Void.class);
    }

}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Flux<Person> getAll() {
        return personRepository.findAll().switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty());
    }

    public Mono<Person> getById(final String id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Mono update(final String id, final Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public Mono save(final Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public Mono delete(final String id) {
        final Mono<Person> dbPerson = getById(id);
        if (Objects.isNull(dbPerson)) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return getById(id).switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty()).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(personToBeDeleted -> personRepository
                .delete(personToBeDeleted).then(Mono.just(personToBeDeleted)));
    }
}
```

I understand everything except the `save` and `update` methods. I don't understand why we use `flatMap` in this situation.
Why is this so, and how can I write the implementation of the **update** method in my **Handler**.

### Updated

Let's see the method **save()** in Handler

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> save(ServerRequest request) {
        final Mono<Person> person = request.bodyToMono(Person.class);
        return ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(fromPublisher(person.flatMap(personService::save), Person.class));
    }
```

I think the fact is that we have already received:

```
final Mono<Person> person = request.bodyToMono(Person.class);
```

and then we do:

```
personService::save
```

As a result, we get Mono< Mono< Person>>

flatMap is just like map, except that it unpacks the return value of the lambda given if the value is itself contained in a `Publisher<T>`. In our case, the `personService.save(T)` method returns a `Mono<T>`. If we’d used map instead of `flatMap(T)`, we’d have a `Mono< Mono< T>>`, when what we really want is a `Mono<T>`. We can cleanly solve this problem using flatMap.

Am I right or is this statement wrong?

Comment: your update comment is exactly right, you can add that as a self-answer ;)

Comment: Thank you! And help me please to understand why I need to use .body(fromPublisher) ? Thanks

Comment: WebFlux is entirely non-blocking. It sends the headers first, then is capable of sending a body that is not yet entirely "computed", by sending chunks to the remote client as the corresponding data is generated and emitted by the `Publisher` you pass to `body` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe you can give me link to read about this part ? I mean .body(fromPublisher). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> why you need flatMap.

These are my ideas, the answer varies depending on whether you it works on Mono or Flux.

1.

javadoc of method map and flatMap shows their usage:

> map: Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} by applying a synchronous function to it.
>
> flatMap: Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} asynchronously, returning the value emitted by another {@link Mono} (possibly changing the value type).

That says, considering `flatMap` and `map` as a pipeline with input and output, you use `map` when the output is the same item , otherwise, use `flatMap`. Check this:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> influCRUD(ServerRequest req) {
    return req.bodyToMono(S.class) // the pipline begins with S class.
       .map(s -> {s.setF1(f1); s.setF2(f2); return s;}) // the pipeline has the same intput and output, i.e. object s, you use map.
       .flatMap(s -> webClient // the pipeline has S input, and T output, you use flatMap
            .post()
            .uri(uri)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(s))
            .retrive()
            .bodyToMono(T.class) 
        ).flatMap(t -> ServerResponse // now the pipeline changes again, you use flatMap.
           .ok()
           .contentType()
           .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(t))
        );
}
```

it deserves to mention that `map` can have different object as output as well.

2. flatMap processes every items

the above reason is usefull for `Mono` producer. For `Flux`, `flatMap` processes every items, while `map` processes all items (or one item). this is the same as they are in lambda. In case you want to process every item, you use `flatMap`.

3. flatMap takes off one layer of Mono for you.

Look at their declaration:

`<R> Mono<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)`

and

`<R> Mono<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Mono<? extends R>> transformer)`

`Function` does nothing but `a -> b`, when `b` is the output of another `Producer/Subsciber` (this is very likely when you use reactive programming) like the `webClient` part in the former example, it is in the form of Mono or Flux. By using flatMap, it returns `Mono<R>` for you, where map returns `Mono<Mono<R>>`, as they are stated in the function declaration.

I am a beginner in reative programming too, **more than welcome to correct this**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But can you give me a link with your example with WebClient ? Thanks

Comment: "my example with WebClient" is in my post. And you can find more references in official website https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux